# Why does this setInterval/document.write code work on Chrome but not on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Here is a simple program that prints numbers one to ten on the browser window.

```js
var t = 1;
var a = function timer() {
  if (t < 11) {
    document.write(t + "<br/>");
    t = t + 1;
  } else {
    clearInterval(handle);
  }
}
var handle = setInterval(a, 100);
```

This works on Chrome (the numbers 1 to 10 appear with a brief delay between them) but doesn't work on Firefox (just 1 appears, and no errors). Why?

I understand I could use `console.log`, but that's not the point. Why is `document.write` working differently between Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Once the page has loaded, the document is closed. You can't use `document.write` on it any more, as it will instead create a new document, effectively overwriting the page you have in the browser. Use something more sensible, like DOM methods or (at least for testing purposes) `console.log`.

Comment: Works fine in firefox in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/gvc4bh8v/  Had to change to console.log though, since document.write isnt allowed by fiddle.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Right. So the question is, why isn't Chrome doing that? http://jsbin.com/lucajut - On Chrome, it shows the numbers appearing 1 to 10, but on Firefox it stops at 1.

Comment: @AdamKonieska Funny how changing the bit of code that makes it not work, suddenly makes it work :p

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good question. I have no idea.

Comment: I'm surprised by multiple aspects of this. That Chrome does 1-10, and that Firefox stops at 1 rather than showing 1, then **replacing** it with 2, then 3, until it just shows 10 at the end.

Comment: For me, Opera and Safari follow Chrome's behavior while IE follows Firefox's. The plot thickens.

Comment: In my opinion, `document.write` should never be a problem in any code, because it should only ever be seen on websites that haven't been updated since the turn of the millenium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in <s>Chrome</s> WebKit; according to [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903556/why-does-this-setinterval-work-on-chrome-but-not-on-firefox/34903878#comment57544084_34903878), it also happens on Safari.

Calling [`document.write`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-document-write) after the main parsing of the page is complete involves an implicit call to `document.open`. [According to the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-document-open), calling `document.open` should destroy the document, remove all event handlers, and discard all tasks. That means what Firefox is doing is correct, because it shows 1 in a blank document. It doesn't keep going because the task scheduled by the `setInterval` has been discarded.

As you've noted, sometimes the Firefox spinner keeps going, like it's expecting something else to happen. I like [Adam Konieska's theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903556/why-does-this-setinterval-work-on-chrome-but-not-on-firefox/34903878#comment57543869_34903878) about why that is: When we did the `document.write(1)`, we implicitly did  a `document.open`, and it's waiting for a `document.close`. And in fact, if we add a `document.close` to your code to test that, the spinner doesn't stick around:

```js
var t = 1;
var a = function timer() {
  if (t < 11) {
    document.write(t + "<br/>");
    t = t + 1;
    document.close(); // Just to test Firefox's spinner
  } else {
    clearInterval(handle);
  }
}
var handle = setInterval(a, 100);
```

Comment: but why does the Firefox loader icon on the tab keeps going round and round as if it is looking for something?

Comment: @BA: For me, it's unreliable about whether it does that. I wouldn't be surprised if that were a Firefox bug. Putting `document.write` inside a `setInterval` is a fairly unusual thing to do, probably not well-tested.

Comment: @BA probably because its lacking `document.close()`

Comment: @AdamKonieska: Oooh, I think you're onto something there. I wonder why it doesn't happen every time?

Comment: @AdamKonieska: No. That doesn't make any difference. Try creating a simple page with static statements: `document.open; document.write('1'); document.write('2'); document.close();` and see what happens. It still prints `1` and stops there.

Comment: @AdamKonieska: Yup, you're right, just tested by adding a `document.close`.

Comment: I Can confirm the same behavior on safari

Comment: @Abhitalks: That's because there's an implicit `document.close` once the main parsing of the document is complete.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Fine. That stops the spinner in `setinterval` case. But, even without that, using just static successive writes, yields the same result in Firefox!

Comment: @Abhitalks of course it does, that's the expected behavior.

Comment: @AdamKonieska: By that logic [**this**](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.html) should never work?

Comment: @Abhitalks there is only 1 document.write in that file.  No problems there.

Comment: @Abhitalks: When the page is first being loaded, there's (for all intents and purposes) an implicit `document.open`. JavaScript code in script tags is run *synchronously* with that parsing process (unless the tags have `async` or `defer`), so `document.write` called immediately in code is writing to an open document. When the page is fully parsed, there's an implicit `document.close`. The reason the OP's behavior is different is that it's calling `document.write` **after** the end of that process, via `setInterval`.

Comment: @Abhitalks it may be easier to think of it as _"If the document is not open for writing, implicitly call `document.open`"_. In the example you've shown, the document is still open for writing as we've not reached `</html>` yet, so `document.open` does not get called. Yes, this also means the result of `document.write` can be subject to race conditions, e.g. on a poor connection the questioners example may complete before the page has finished loading

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. That was much clearer. My bad in the earlier comment, somehow my browser couldn't refresh after code changes. Tried again and it works with multiple writes without the setinterval, just fine. setinterval puts that code into scheduler and javascript happily goes about completing the current stack closing the document eventually. For a moment I was stumped thinking FF was going wrong here!

Comment: @AdamKonieska: Thanks. But that doesn't matter. It works just fine with multiple writes. My problem was not getting the browser refreshed in time, and so thought FF was wrong. Face Palm.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the points by T.J. Chowder about the webkit bug, consider these two scripts and why your code specifically doesn't work like you may have expected.

### Script 1

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>foo</title>
    <script>    
    t = 1;
    var a = function timer() {
        if (t < 11) {
            document.write(t + "<br/>");

            t = t + 1;
        }

    }
    setInterval(a, 100);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        alert('page fully loaded')
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Script 2

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>foo</title>
    <script>  
    for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++) { 
        document.write(i + "<br />");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        alert('page fully loaded')
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Results

### Script 1

In the first, `setInterval()` is triggering again *after* the page is closed.  You'll see the alert message indicating the page had executed fully, and the document is closed for writing. *After* that happens, you will see the `document.write` being triggered by the first interval.  This unloads the old, previously closed document, and adds only `1<br />` to the page.

Since the old document has been unloaded, the existing javascript is gone and there is nothing else to execute beyond the first iteration.

### Script 2

In the second script, `document.write` is executed multiple times while the current document is still open.  Since the `document.write` functions are executed *before* the document is closed naturally, the original contents of the document are never overwritten.

## Conclusions

Its better to interact with DOM elements directly than to use `document.write`.

There is some more good reading on it here: https://pigeoto.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/why-doesnt-document-write-work-with-setinterval/