# Dynamic Moment.js Difference

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i'm trying to display a difference between dates using moment.js and update it every second. **More specificly my age**.
I'm using *moment.js* and a plugin called *moment-precise-range.js*
I get the difference correctly:

```
function fecha() {
  var m1 = moment('1989-11-29 04:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  var m2 = moment(moment(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  var diff = moment.preciseDiff(m1, m2);
  document.write(diff)
  } 
fecha()
```

And then, I'm trying to use SetInterval():

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
      var m1 = moment('1989-11-29 04:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      var m2 = moment(moment(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      var diff = moment.preciseDiff(m1, m2);
      document.write(diff)
      }
```

But it doesn't work. (I think it keeps loading the webpage but not sure)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Note that `document.write`s behaviour depends on browser. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903556/why-does-this-setinterval-document-write-code-work-on-chrome-but-not-on-firefox

Comment: works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/9dk1zpss/

Comment: @BrianShamblen Used your code but changing `.value` to `.innerHTML` of a `<div>` Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your code is crashing at

```
moment.preciseDiff(m1,m2);
```

Here's a working sample of your code with the regular moment.diff()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

    function myTimer() {
          var m1 = moment('1989-11-29 04:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
          var m2 = moment(moment(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
          document.write(m2.diff(m1) + "\n");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As I used `document.write` and you used it too it's writing a new date next to the last one. Also, is showing numbers only (don't know what kind of format they are) But thanks anyway