# Very Simple Time Interval In Java Script

Tags: javascript

I just want the word "tuna" to repeat every second on my web page, from what I understand this should be accomplished by using the code below. I'm not sure what I did wrong but every time I try it the word "tuna" is only put on the page once and doesn't repeat every second like I want it to.

```
function doSomething(){
    document.write("Tuna ");
}

setInterval("doSomething()", 1000);
```

I've also tried

```
var something = function doSomething(){
    document.write("Tuna ");
}

setInterval("something", 1000);
```

Comment: Be aware that you're passing a string into `setInterval`, not a reference to a function.

Comment: reading the docs would have saved you a lot of time..

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903556/why-does-this-setinterval-document-write-code-work-on-chrome-but-not-on-firefox

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval(doSomething, 1000);` is how you use setInterval. setInterval expects it's first argument to be a function. Not a string, like "something", and not the result of the funciton, eg `doSomething()`, just the function itself, `doSomething`

alternatively, `setInterval(function(){doSomething();}, 1000);`

https://jsfiddle.net/067zv7af/

Comment: I also tried that and the same problem is happening, do you think my browser (firefox) may be blocking it from repeating?

Comment: I don't know, it should absolutely work. Look at the jsfiddle I linked. Does that work in firefox?

Comment: The problem is with `document.write`, not with the interval syntax. The first code in the OP's post is correct.

Comment: i checked the link in firefox and it didnt seem to work either, although when i went to chrome it worked fine, is there any way to fix this problem in firefox? i much prefer it compared to using chrome haha

Comment: @KiloLime you could add a `div` element with some id to your page and add your text for the div by doing `document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = "YOUR_TEXT_HERE";` instead of `document.write`